# Intent for Installing .apk via Web URL

Tags: android

From an Android app, I like to install an apk file from a web server. This apk file contains an update for the app.

All tutorials do this in two steps:

1  Download the file and save it to the phone's sd card memory.
  2  Create a `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)` and run the method `setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("....` of this intent.

However, since Android Nougat, you get into trouble with permission to access the SD card memory. There are (complicated) solutions for this problem.

My question: is there a way to create an Intent, which gets a web URL as source for the apk file. Something like `intent.setDataAndType(new URL("http://....")`

This is easy for the programmer and it provides as clear interface from the program to the Android system

Comment: I think it's impossible. You can use brand SDK, like samsung knox to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to create an Intent, which gets a web URL as source for the apk file. Something like intent.setDataAndType(new URL("http://....")

Not as part of standard Android. The app installer knows about the `file` scheme, and on Android 7.0+ it knows about the `content` scheme. It does not know about the `http` scheme.

> All tutorials do this in two steps... Download the file and save it to the phone's sd card memory.

Few tutorials do that. Most download the file to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html), which is not the same as [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). On Android 7.0+, you also have the option of downloading to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) and using `FileProvider` (or the equivalent) to make it available via a `content` `Uri`.